# How to remove the "Go to live visual tree" / "Enable selection" / "Display layout adorners" overlay when debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

How do I remove the box with the 3 icons when debugging?

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know how to just quickly move it temporarily?  It is generally useful but occasionally you just want to quickly move it out of the way so you can click the element underneath it.

Comment: @SimonSmith, I have updated my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727482/how-to-remove-the-go-to-live-visual-tree-enable-selection-display-layou/36727876#36727876) below, you can easily toggle the runtime tools via a button in the 'Live Visual Tree' pane in Visual Studio.

Comment: FYI, in case you hadn't noticed, you can also _minimize_ the box by clicking the parallel line glyph at the bottom. That will "roll it up" for you. It won't completely disappear that way, but it is useful to access things behind it.

Comment: Agreed.  This thing is a ****ing annoyance.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Just simply uncheck `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML -> Show runtime tools in application`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As of VS2019 16.8 this has been moved to `Debugging - Hot Reload - Enable in-app toolbar`

Comment: They should add a right click context menu on the damn thing to disable it instead of having it be completely nameless with no tooltip so that you can't even find the option without googling it. Dark UX.

Answer (score 37):

Just uncheck "Show runtime tools in application"

[image: Settings option to toggle]

A quicker alternative can be found in a toggle on the Live Visual Tree pane.

[image: Live Visual Tree pane toggle]

Answer (score 5):

It's moved in VS2022 to Tools -> Debugging here:

[image]