# Remove Universal Windows Platform Black toolbar

Tags: toolbar, uwp, template10

Might be a really stupid question but anyone got any idea how to get rid of the black toolbar appearing when running my application. I'm using Template10 as well.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's buttons for debugging your application.
If you deploy your app and run it - your app will run without them. 
Watch this thread if you want to manage:
[How to remove the “Go to live visual tree” / “Enable selection” / “Display layout adorners” overlay when debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727482/how-to-remove-the-go-to-live-visual-tree-enable-selection-display-layou)

Comment: Thank you for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

There is a small button at the bottom of the black toolbar, which when clicked it hides the biggest part of it (in case you don't want to see it while debugging).