# WPF Window control: How hide Grip at top (which obliterates title)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

Since Visual Studio 2022 and latest 2019 builds, ALL of our application Window Dialogs
"feature" a grip which overwrites the title text.

[image: See below]

I've tried combinations of:
ResizeMode="NoResize"
WindowStyle="None"
Transparency etc.
I've also tried WindowsChrome caption stuff.
All to no success. I imagine it's part of the frame.
Basically, our users don't want to see or use the grip.

Any ideas.
Thanks. Where would we be without Stack Overflow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727482/how-to-remove-the-go-to-live-visual-tree-enable-selection-display-layou

Comment: Thanks Ash. Must have defaulted to 'ON' when 2022 installed.

Comment: well, it is useful for developers, so it is enabled by default. user should cannot see it, because it is a part of VS, not compiled app